# Show that $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \operatorname{erf} \left( \frac{b_i-x}{\sqrt{2}} \right) \to x$ for some sequence $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$

Tags: real-analysis, approximation-theory

Consider the following function
\begin{align}
f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n  a_i \operatorname{erf} \left( \frac{b_i-x}{\sqrt{2}} \right) 
\end{align}
where $\operatorname{erf} $ is the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).

**Question:** Can we show that there exist sequences $ \{a_k\}$ and $\{b_i\}$ such that
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) \to x
\end{align}
for all x.

I attempted a proof of this by using Taylor series of ${\rm erf}$. However, that argument ended up being a dead end because it was not clear how to choose $a_i$ and $t_i$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}$ be the derivative of your $\mathrm{erf}(x/\sqrt{2})$.
Then we have
$$\sqrt{2\pi}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x-t)^2/2}dt=
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \int_{k/n}^{(k+1)/n}e^{-(x-t)^2/2}dt.$$
Let us compare this with the infinite integral sum of the same integral
$$S_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x-k/n)^2},$$
which is evidently uniformly convergent. The difference between the terms of the two series is at most
$$\frac{1}{n}\max\left\{ \left|(d/dt)e^{-(x-t)^2/2}\right|:t\in[k/n,(k+1)/n]\right\}$$
$$\leq \frac{1}{n^2}e^{-(x-k/n)^2},$$
and the sum of these differences for $-\infty<k<\infty$ is $O(1/n)\to 0,
$ uniformly in $x$.

So the difference between the integral and the integral sum
tends to $0$, uniformly on the whole line.
Thus $(\sqrt{2\pi})^{-1}S_n\to 1$ uniformly, and integrating from $0$ to $x$
we obtain the convergence of integrals uniform on compacts.

This shows how to choose your $b_k$ in practice: choose them equidistant with small distance,  and $a_k$ independent of $k$.